# ASP.NET put class in Order

Tags: asp.net

I have a class like so:

```
public class CellModel
{
    public uint scheduleTaskID { get; set; }
    public string task { get; set; }
    public string baselineDate { get; set; }
    public string scheduledDate { get; set; }
    public string actualDate { get; set; }
    public string finishedDate { get; set; }
    public string expectedStart { get; set; }
    public string expectedFinish { get; set; }
    public string plusMinus { get; set; }
    public string completedBy { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
    public bool isEditableRow { get; set; }
    public uint sortOrder { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return scheduleTaskID.ToString();
    }
}
```

and right now, I have 3 class items with these sortOrder (31, 30, 32) what I am trying to do is put these class items in order of sortOrder or its (30, 31, 32)

I have tried the following:

```
cells.OrderBy(c => c.sortOrder);
```

but it didn't do anything, the order remains (31, 30, 32) What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrderBy returns a new List in the given order. It does not change the order on which OrderBy is applied though.

```
foreach(var cell in cells.OrderBy(c => c.sortOrder).ToList())
```

Comment: This is working, is there away to use this in a for loop?

Comment: I updated it there